# Is there a way to open attribute tables undocked by default in ArcGIS Pro 2.2?

Tags: arcgis-pro

I can undock attribute tables by dragging them out of the application window to another monitor. Field view, subtypes view, etc. then opens in that undocked window. However, when i open another attribute table it annoyingly opens inside the main application window. Again, I can drag that attribute table out of the application and dock it by itself or into my already open undocked attribute window.

**Is there a way to change the default behaviour so that all attribute tables open undocked?** Ideally, is there a way to open all attribute tables into a single undocked window as tabs - same as ArcMap.  Since I can do this manually by dragging things around I figure there should be a way.

Comment: Right from the initial beta of Pro my feedback was negative for the opening of each table in the main window but I never got a response to it.  Later for 1.3 an ESRI analyst went over most of my issues and submitted them to others.  I just checked my request #01856568 Allow tables in ArcGIS Pro to be opened separate from the main view window as the default was closed and this replaced it 
[ENH-000100403 Include an option in Pro for newly opened table views to open by default in the various docking target locations.]  But I can't find the status of that request.  Perhaps it needs an Idea?

Comment: Thanks @johns. Good info! This qualifies as an answer. Please copy and paste into an answer and I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right from the initial beta of Pro my feedback was negative for the opening of each table in the main window but I never got a response to it. Later for 1.3 an ESRI analyst went over most of my issues and submitted them to others. I just checked my request #01856568 Allow tables in ArcGIS Pro to be opened separate from the main view window as the default was closed and this replaced it [ENH-000100403 Include an option in Pro for newly opened table views to open by default in the various docking target locations.] But I can't find the status of that request. Perhaps it needs an Idea?

Answer (score 1):

At least in ArcGIS Pro 2.7, this can be done.  Go into Options, then User Interface under Applications.  Set default options for Tables to  As A Separate Floating Window and check Stack Additional Views on Top.

Comment: Rick Moore's advice worked just fine for me. Thanks